# Understanding race condition in Go

Tags: go, time

I have the following very simple code:

```
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    tt := time.AfterFunc(10*time.Microsecond, func() { log.Fatal("bleh!") })
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Microsecond)
    tt.Stop()
}
```

Now, it should seem that it would do nothing, and when I run it on the Go playground, it just quietly exits as expected, but when I run this on my Macbook, I invariably get errors, like:

```
go run example.go
2017/03/02 22:21:50 bleh!
2017/03/02 22:21:50 bleh!
exit status 1
```

And I can put that time on the `AfterFunc` quite high indeed, even as high as 50 or 100 μs and I'll still get the occasional "bleh!" and death. What are the guarantees around `time.Sleep` in Go? And what is a better way of testing that something ran within a specific amount of time?

Comment: I assume that sleeping is sometimes leading to a context switch. This leads to the process sometimes losing CPU focus for long enough that the timeout occurs. This does not occur on the playground because it does not time in the same way a normal computer does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guarantee is that `time.Sleep(2 * time.Microsecond)` will sleep for *at least* 2 microseconds, and `time.AfterFunc(10 * time.Microsecond, ...)` will call its callback after *at least* 10 microseconds. No upper limit is guaranteed (the underlying operating system could do anything it wants), and no relative ordering is guaranteed — if the sleep happens to take more than 10 microseconds, then the `AfterFunc` could end up before or after it.

If you used reasonably long periods of time then it's *very likely* that you would observe things happening in the right order, because the `Sleep`ing goroutine would get scheduled before the timer expired. But a microsecond is a very short period of time, and so, unscientifically speaking, deadlines that happen within microseconds of each other are very likely to happen in whatever order they feel like.

The playground uses a [modified runtime that fakes time](https://blog.golang.org/playground), which incidentally is the best approach for testing as well. Modifying the runtime isn't really practical for most, but you might try the [clockwork](https://godoc.org/github.com/jonboulle/clockwork) package which provides an interface to both real and fake clock objects. Otherwise, follow the same approach yourself — if you want something to be testable, it can't depend on `time`, because `time` is global and irreproducible. Instead, it has to get its notifications from some component that uses `time` in production, but is replaceable for testing.

Comment: Thanks! And really nice to find that clockwork package, that's exactly what I need. I was essentially naively trying to test something and when I scaled it down to microseconds, everything exploded. :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### `func Sleep`

> Sleep pauses the current goroutine for at least the duration d. A negative or zero duration causes Sleep to return immediately.

The most significant here is that "**at least**". It means `Sleep` could take more time than a passed value. This behavior is dependent from a current state of os.

```
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    tt := time.AfterFunc(
        10*time.Microsecond,
        func() {log.Fatal("bleh!") }) // has time to be executed
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Microsecond) // Slept more than 10 microsecond
    tt.Stop()
}
```